# Port windows phone 8.1 app to android

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is it possible to port my windows phone 8.1 (universal) app to Android? without using Xamarin.
thanks

Comment: Port it to Android and iOS?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magic

Comment: That was no question. That is what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There is not such thing that converts one os native app into other os nativ app. You can write for example in phonegap to support many os with same code, but this is other approach. I think if you manage to write such a system that can covert one native app into another you will be rich man.